# Simple format date parse fails in Android

Tags: java, android, date, time

I used

```
public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        String fDate = format.format(date);

        return fDate;
    }
```

to get current time as string in android and save it into database, It worked fine until I found '2015-09-23 12:48:04:55.845' in database.
Can someone help me explain why there is an extra field in the time? Thanks.

Comment: Because you are using "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"?

Comment: can you show us dates that did work, please? and what was the error?

Comment: Please see that 12:48:04:55.845, my string is HH:mm:ss.SSS, the issue is number 55, its spare!

Comment: what is the format of the date field on your database table?

Comment: @SwanZus I think you should use `long` datatype to insert date into database.... Instead of using the formatted `String`.

Comment: the date field in my database is TEXT format and this is the sample (right result ) 2015-09-23 11:45:34.239 . But have only field like my question is wrong.

Comment: @StillLearnin my format is HH:mm:ss.SSS and string 12:48:04:55.845 do not match. 55 is spare. The right must be 12:48:04.845

Comment: *FYI:* `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` is the same as `new Date()`.

Comment: Curious: Why are your inserting a date into the database as a string, instead of a datetime/timestamp column?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but is an important point. Always be sure to check the android developer documentation.  SimpleDateFormat uses a slightly different formatting expression than the one available in the JDK.  for instance, timezone formatting is different (z zz zzz and zzzz).

Comment: @Andreas I saved as string for my business and I can call many times without parsing.

Comment: Thank @eddiecubed, I will check timezone because I set it to default, the issue can be it.

Answer (score 1):

Because someone inserted that value into the database.

Whether that was an earlier iteration of your code that wasn't working right, or somewhere else in your code, or someone inserting/updating directly to the database, that is unknown and will be difficult to find out, at least with the little information we have.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. Its still worked fine, and sometime had a field like that. This issue have occurred in the past. I will check all of my code about database.